# Stop and resume optimisation

Tags: c++, nlopt

I am using `nlopt`'s c++ interface to solve non-linear optimisation problems.

```
nlopt::opt opt;
opt.set_maxeval(10);
opt.set_max_objective(foo);

double result;
std::vector<double> params(10,0);
opt.optimize(params, result);

// later on in the code
opt.optimize(params, result); // this uses the updated param values, but the step size starts from scratch
```

However, I'd like the last line to continue optimising not just with the last `params` value, but also with the `step_size` that was last used, but I don't think I have access to that value.

How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: What do you mean by ```but I don't think I have access to that value```. What's the point of optimizing if you are not able to read out the result? And what kind of warm-start are we talking about? Setting an initial-point or the whole solver-internals?

Comment: @sascha I'm trying to get access to the step size that was used when the optimisation finished, so that I can start the process again with that step size. I've edited the post to try and make this clearer.

Comment: In your case, params is the initial state of the variables for the optimization, you put the last (or best) result in there and start the optimization with that

Comment: @fernando.reyes yes but how do I get the step size to start where it finished off?

Comment: Which algorithm are you using?

Comment: @quant Is that useful? http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt_C-plus-plus_Reference#Initial_step_size

Comment: @sascha I'm using derivative-free local and global optimisers.

Comment: [This](https://www.mail-archive.com/nlopt-discuss@ab-initio.mit.edu/msg00412.html) makes me think that chances are very low that you will find this functionality (at least in a general way without modifying the code). Yes, the comment is quite old, but the dev seems to be a bit sceptical about a general-api for this.

Comment: @sasha hmm, I think you might be right. If you post that comment as the answer I'll wait a day or so to see if someone comes up with something, otherwise I'll mark yours as the answer.

Comment: In my opinion, it does not qualify as an answer. Anyway: good luck with your problem. It looks like you need to get your hands dirty to add this functionality for some a-priori decided solver. And if you pursue this: maybe add a request/question to [nlopt@github](https://github.com/stevengj/nlopt). But take your time to add a bit more information (like the exact solver-setup). The project seems to be still active! [That's interesting](https://github.com/stevengj/nlopt/issues/58).

Answer (score 1):

*Caveat:* This is a guess--something for you to try.

The object has a member `double *dx` that stores the step. If you do *not* explicitly specify values for initial step, the `dx` value is allocated at the start of `nlopt_optimize` with default values and freed at the end.

Look at the API documentation: http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt_Reference

There are two functions of interest: `nlopt_get_initial_step` and `nlopt_set_initial_step`.

Normal usage is using values of your own choosing, call `set_initial_step` with them. Then, you call `optimize`. Then, you repeat this process with your own new values.

But, for what you want, try this:

Initially, use `get_initial_step` to get the default values. Then, do an explicit set with `set_initial_step`. This will make the internal `dx` array in the object persist after `optimize` is called. I checked this in the `nlopt` source code.

Now, call `optimize`.

Now, peek at the `dx` array inside the object.

*If* you get updated values--you're home free. If not, well, you may need to write some custom code.

You may just be able to continue calling `optimize` but *not* doing the `set_initial_step` call the second or third time.

---

Pseudo code for the "normal" case:

```
// normal usage

obj.set_initial_step(my_values_1);
obj.optimize();

obj.set_initial_step(my_values_2);
obj.optimize();
```

---

Pseudo code for the "trick":

```
// special usage

obj.get_initial_step(x,my_values_1);
obj.set_initial_step(my_values_1);
obj.optimize();

// check to see if the values have been updated relative to my_values_1

// if the trick works, this should use the updated values
obj.optimize();

// if the trick works, this should use the updated values
obj.optimize();
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Peeking at the object's `dx` value requires a bit of hacking/trickery. The standard `nlopt.h` treats `nlopt_opt` as an opaque pointer. The actual struct definition is *only* available from `nlopt-internal.h` which means you have to have the full source and extract the struct definition from that.

That's if you want positive confirmation that the values have changed. You may be able to infer [by some method] that you're getting different values (e.g. your limit function(s) detect something) without having to peek at `dx`.

Or, you can "wing it" by providing updated values using the API in its intended manner.

I tried a test program and didn't see the `dx` change, but I know little [read: nothing] about NL optimization, so I have no idea if my test case was valid or would show valid changes to `dx`